# A method that generates a Comparator<String> using lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda

Given below is an exercise from the book *Java SE 8 for the Really Impatient( by Cay S. Horstmann:

> Write a method that generates a Comparator that can be normal or
>   reversed, case-sensitive or case-insensitive, space-sensitive or
>   space-insensitive, or any combination thereof. Your method should
>   return a lambda expression.

Is there a better (efficient, elegant) way to do it than below?

```
public static final int COMPARE_REVERSED = 0x01;
public static final int COMPARE_CASE_INSENSITIVE = 0x02;
public static final int COMPARE_SPACE_INSENSITIVE = 0x04;

public static Comparator<String> getComparator(int flags) {

    return (s1, s2) -> {
        if (has(flags, COMPARE_REVERSED)) {
            String temp = s1;
            s1 = s2;
            s2 = temp;
        }
        if (has(flags, COMPARE_SPACE_INSENSITIVE)) {
            s1 = s1.replaceAll("\\s", "");
            s2 = s2.replaceAll("\\s", "");
        }
        if (has(flags, COMPARE_CASE_INSENSITIVE)) {
            return s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s2);
        }
        return s1.compareTo(s2);
    };
}

public static boolean has(int flags, int FLAG) {
    return (flags & FLAG) != 0;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

This seems as efficient as it gets, to me.

In terms of elegance, [Joshua Bloch (in Effective Java)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321356683) recommends to stop using bit fields, use `EnumSet` instead.

The first step is to change your bit fields to an `enum`:

```
public enum Mode {
    COMPARE_REVERSED,
    COMPARE_CASE_INSENSITIVE,
    COMPARE_SPACE_INSENSITIVE
}
```

Next, change your method to take a `Set` instead of an `int`:

```
public static Comparator<String> getComparator(Set<Mode> flags) {
    return (s1, s2) -> {
        if (flags.contains(Mode.COMPARE_REVERSED)) {
            String temp = s1;
            s1 = s2;
            s2 = temp;
        }
        if (flags.contains(Mode.COMPARE_SPACE_INSENSITIVE)) {
            s1 = s1.replaceAll("\\s", "");
            s2 = s2.replaceAll("\\s", "");
        }
        if (flags.contains(Mode.COMPARE_CASE_INSENSITIVE)) {
            return s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s2);
        }
        return s1.compareTo(s2);
    };
}
```

You could call this method with any `Set`, but it will be best to call with an `EnumSet`, for example:

```
getComparator(EnumSet.of(Mode.COMPARE_CASE_INSENSITIVE, Mode.COMPARE_SPACE_INSENSITIVE));
```

Why is this better?

- You don't need to worry about setting the bit fields correctly to be mutually exclusive
- You don't need the `has` method anymore, now you can use simple `Set.contains`
- You don't need the `... | ...` bit operations anymore, `EnumSet.of(...)` is simple and clean

In short (quoted from the book):

> No more bit twiddling, `EnumSet` does all the hard work for you.

I would also add a convenience method for the case of no flags:

```
public static Comparator<String> getComparator() {
    return getComparator(Collections.<Mode>emptySet());
}
```

And of course, a bunch of unit tests, for example:

```
@Test
public void testNormalComparator() {
    Comparator<String> comparator = ComparatorGenerator.getComparator();
    assertNotEquals(0, comparator.compare("hello", "Hello"));
    assertEquals(0, comparator.compare("hello", "hello"));
}

@Test
public void testCaseInsensitiveComparator() {
    Comparator<String> comparator = ComparatorGenerator.getComparator(EnumSet.of(ComparatorGenerator.Mode.COMPARE_CASE_INSENSITIVE));
    assertNotEquals(0, comparator.compare("hello", "xHello"));
    assertEquals(0, comparator.compare("hello", "Hello"));
    assertEquals(0, comparator.compare("hello", "hello"));
}

@Test
public void testReversedComparator() {
    Comparator<String> comparator1 = ComparatorGenerator.getComparator();
    assertEquals(-1, comparator1.compare("hello1", "hello2"));
    Comparator<String> comparator2 = ComparatorGenerator.getComparator(EnumSet.of(ComparatorGenerator.Mode.COMPARE_REVERSED));
    assertEquals(1, comparator2.compare("hello1", "hello2"));
}

@Test
public void testCaseAndSpaceInsensitiveComparator() {
    Comparator<String> comparator = ComparatorGenerator.getComparator(EnumSet.of(ComparatorGenerator.Mode.COMPARE_CASE_INSENSITIVE, ComparatorGenerator.Mode.COMPARE_SPACE_INSENSITIVE));
    assertNotEquals(0, comparator.compare("hello there", "x hello there"));
    assertEquals(0, comparator.compare("HELLO there", "h e llo there"));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your answer is already pretty good, and after @janos's refactoring using `EnumSet` you would/should probably stop IRL.

But what is an improvement (optimization) depends on your values (loss function). if you resolve to "extract till you drop", you can find a few more refactorings to be made.

- One thing that isn't DRY is `if (has(flags, someFlag)) {do something};` snippets.
- those snippets are not reified (they are not explicit methods/variables etc)
- The flag and the snippet it affects do not have an explicit relation.
- the parameters are assigned.

I started with extracting the bodies of `if` statements to static methods of signature `Comparator<String> spaceInsensitive(Comparator<String> c)`.
I then converted these methods to constants of type `Function<Comparator<String>, Comparator<String>>`.
And moved these constants into the @janos's `Mode` enum, so that the I have a 1-to-1 mapping between the option and the transformation it does:

```
public enum Mode {
    REVERSED(c -> c.reversed()),
    CASE_INSENSITIVE(c -> (s1, s2) -> c.compare(
                                            s1.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT), 
                                            s2.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT))),
    SPACE_INSENSITIVE(c -> (s1, s2) -> c.compare(
                                            s1.replaceAll("\\s", ""), 
                                            s2.replaceAll("\\s", "")));

    public final Function<Comparator<String>, Comparator<String>> transform;

    Mode(Function<Comparator<String>, Comparator<String>> transform) {
        this.transform = transform;
    }
}
```

Extracting the repetitive parts of `CASE_INSENSITIVE` and `SPACE_INSENSITIVE`, we get, (becoming a [Three-Arrow-Java-Programmer](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer) as a side effect) :

```
public enum Mode {
    REVERSED(c -> c.reversed()),
    CASE_INSENSITIVE(transformingEachParam.apply(s -> s.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT))),
    SPACE_INSENSITIVE(transformingEachParam.apply(s -> s.replaceAll("\\s", "")));

    public final Function<Comparator<String>, Comparator<String>> transform;

    Mode(Function<Comparator<String>, Comparator<String>> transform) {
        this.transform = transform;
    }
}

private static final Function<Function<String, String>, Function<Comparator<String>, Comparator<String>>> 
    transformingEachParam = f -> c -> (s1, s2) -> c.compare(f.apply(s1), f.apply(s2));
```

Changing `if`s to ternary operators, for considerations of composability:

```
    public static Comparator<String> getComparator(Set<Mode> flags) {
        Comparator<String> result = Comparator.naturalOrder();
        result = flags.contains(Mode.SPACE_INSENSITIVE) 
                ? Mode.SPACE_INSENSITIVE.transform.apply(result) 
                : result;
        // ... the same for other options ....
        return result;
    }
```

It is now trivial to roll these into a for each loop:

```
    public static Comparator<String> getComparator(Set<Mode> flags) {
        Comparator<String> result = Comparator.naturalOrder();
        for (Mode mode : Mode.values()) {
            result = flags.contains(mode) 
                    ? mode.transform.apply(result) 
                    : result;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

This is another good place to stop, but since we are learning Java 8 let's convert this loop to Stream API. [Stream API does not want us (It is an opinionated API) to write reductions as "start with this value, keep modifying it in that way".](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Reduction) It wants us to use associative and stateless binary operations to combine elements of a stream. Luckily for us [function composition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html#andThen-java.util.function.Function-) is both associative and stateless.

Final form:

```
    public static Comparator<String> getComparator2(Set<Mode> flags) {
        Comparator<String> result = flags.stream()
                .map(m -> m.transform)
                .reduce(Function.identity(), (f1, f2) -> f1.andThen(f2))
                .apply(Comparator.<String>naturalOrder());

        // to fulfill "return a lambda expression" requirement ;)
        return (s1, s2) -> result.compare(s1, s2);
    }
```

Comment: Highly complex but it worked for some tests that i performed.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it against janos's test suite while writing it. Also this is more of an attempt at eliminating as much duplication as possible with little regard towards simplicity. ([DRY](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DontRepeatYourself) over [KISS](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?KissPrinciple)) The last part with `map`/`reduce` is mostly a groaning about the new API.